# Should "They asked me to leave the company" be interpreted as "Hanno chiesto che io lasci la ditta" or 'Mi hanno chiesto di lasciare la ditta"?

Tags: grammar

Duolingo gives the sentence "They asked me to leave the company" and gives the translation as:

"Mi hanno chiesto di lasciare la ditta" and does not accept "Hanno chiesto che io lasci la ditta"

Since there are two subjects and there is a request that is really a demand or exhortation, shouldn't this require the subjunctive?  Why is it wrong?  I realize in informal conversation the subjunctive is sometimes not used but is the subjunctive wrong here?  And if it is wrong, why?

Comment: The construction with the infinitive is perfectly correct and usual, not at all informal; it's the construction with the subjunctive that sounds a bit stilted. With verbs like _chiedere_, _ordinare_, _invitare_, _pregare_, _esortare_ the usual construction is with a suitable preposition and the infinitive.

Comment: I think Duolingo is too strict; the second phrase is perfectly legitimate: it is only a matter style. Does Duolingo also refuse "[Mi] hanno richiesto..."?

Comment: In addition to what @DaG said, there's a small difference in the meaning. While "Mi hanno chiesto di lasciare" is the exact translation, "Hanno chiesto che io lasci la ditta" means that they asked [whoever], and since it's not usual construction if the asked me, we imply that they asked someone else (my boss?) to make me leave.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!